# Can't start Oracle after Virtual Machine restore

Tags: windows, oracle

As part of a project for a customer of mine, they've given me the complete backup of a physical server (taken by Veeam) which I have then used to make a Bare Metal recovery onto a test VM host I have here (VMWare Workstation Pro)

That's all gone fine and windows starts up with all data intact. I'm having issues getting Oracle going though (yes, this is Oracle running on Windows)

From what I can tell, all datafiles and log files are in place. However when I try to start Oracle, this happens

```
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1.6034E+10 bytes
Fixed Size                  2191576 bytes
Variable Size            1.0972E+10 bytes
Database Buffers         5033164800 bytes
Redo Buffers               26554368 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01122: database file 1 failed verification check
ORA-01110: data file 1: 'F:\DB_DATA\LSTEG\SYSTEM01.DBF'
ORA-01207: file is more recent than control file - old control file
```

EDIT

After speaking with the customer again, they've told me that the DBF / LOG files are screwed by the backup. Their expectation is that the current database be "trashed" and the schemas to be recreated and then the actual database backup dmp files to be reimported

But how do you remove all existing schemas if you can't even start the db?

Answer (score 0):

And that is why Veeam should not be used to backup a database while it is online.

Just delete the database, create a new emtpy one then proceed with the rest of the steps:

*"schemas to be recreated and then the actual database backup dmp files to be reimported"*.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I've learnt the hard way the downside of Veeam. I've managed to get the test system up and running now by deleting, recreating using a template of the live db and then reimporting the database backups

Answer (score -1):

**Reason:**  controlfile is older than datafiles.
**Solution:**  re-create controlfile